# Mysql service is eating CPU upto 760%

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 5.7. Suddenly MySQL server CPU Utilaization is very high and RAM memory usage is high. DB hits are very less. Slow query log is not enabled.

```
Not sure what could be a issue.Please suggest how to fix this.

 Please find the innoDB status

    SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
      Type: InnoDB
      Name:
    Status:
    =====================================
    2020-01-03 14:25:49 0x7f2edcaa5700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
    =====================================
    Per second averages calculated from the last 60 seconds
    -----------------
    BACKGROUND THREAD
    -----------------
    srv_master_thread loops: 124 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 48 srv_idle
    srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 172
    ----------
    SEMAPHORES
    ----------
    OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 20222
    OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 433962
    RW-shared spins 0, rounds 102594, OS waits 6345
    RW-excl spins 0, rounds 86040, OS waits 11766
    RW-sx spins 471, rounds 10729, OS waits 182
    Spin rounds per wait: 102594.00 RW-shared, 86040.00 RW-excl, 22.78 RW-sx
    ------------
    TRANSACTIONS
    ------------
    Trx id counter 644151905
    Purge done for trx's n:o < 644151433 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
    History list length 1674
    LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
    ---TRANSACTION 421330135615312, not started
    0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
    --------
    FILE I/O
    --------
    I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
    I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
    I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
    I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
    I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
    I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
    I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
    I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
    I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
    I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
    Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
     ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
    Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
    200407 OS file reads, 5909 OS file writes, 3118 OS fsyncs
    750.27 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 28.72 writes/s, 18.83 fsyncs/s
    -------------------------------------
    INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
    -------------------------------------
    Ibuf: size 1, free list len 4703, seg size 4705, 458 merges
    merged operations:
     insert 315, delete mark 387, delete 0
    discarded operations:
     insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
    Hash table size 3718361, node heap has 732 buffer(s)
    Hash table size 3718361, node heap has 1722 buffer(s)
    Hash table size 3718361, node heap has 33 buffer(s)
    Hash table size 3718361, node heap has 444 buffer(s)
    Hash table size 3718361, node heap has 30318 buffer(s)
    Hash table size 3718361, node heap has 591 buffer(s)
    Hash table size 3718361, node heap has 1120 buffer(s)
    Hash table size 3718361, node heap has 1760 buffer(s)
    1183013.37 hash searches/s, 59626.41 non-hash searches/s
    ---
    LOG
    ---
    Log sequence number 1231417336087
    Log flushed up to   1231417336087
    Pages flushed up to 1231417336087
    Last checkpoint at  1231417336078
    0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
    1379 log i/o's done, 6.48 log i/o's/second
    ----------------------
    BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
    ----------------------
    Total large memory allocated 15392047104
    Dictionary memory allocated 4053431
    Buffer pool size   917392
    Free buffers       680532
    Database pages     200140
    Old database pages 74036
    Modified db pages  0
    Pending reads      0
    Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
    Pages made young 5, not young 0
    0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
    Pages read 200023, created 117, written 4266
    0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
    Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
    Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
    LRU len: 200140, unzip_LRU len: 0
    I/O sum[0]:cur[2136], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
    ----------------------
    INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
    ----------------------
    ---BUFFER POOL 0
    Buffer pool size   114674
    Free buffers       84581
    Database pages     25491
    Old database pages 9429
    Modified db pages  0
    Pending reads      0
    Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
    Pages made young 0, not young 0
    0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
    Pages read 25486, created 5, written 718
    0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
    Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
    Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
    LRU len: 25491, unzip_LRU len: 0
    I/O sum[0]:cur[267], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
    ---BUFFER POOL 1
    Buffer pool size   114674
    Free buffers       85011
    Database pages     25079
    Old database pages 9277
    Modified db pages  0
    Pending reads      0
    Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
    Pages made young 0, not young 0
    0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
    Pages read 25078, created 1, written 329
    0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
    Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
    Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
    LRU len: 25079, unzip_LRU len: 0
    I/O sum[0]:cur[267], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
    ---BUFFER POOL 2
    Buffer pool size   114674
    Free buffers       84531
    Database pages     25554
    Old database pages 9453
    Modified db pages  0
    Pending reads      0
    Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
    Pages made young 1, not young 0
    0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
    Pages read 25550, created 4, written 386
    0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
    Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
    Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
    LRU len: 25554, unzip_LRU len: 0
    I/O sum[0]:cur[267], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
    ---BUFFER POOL 3
    Buffer pool size   114674
    Free buffers       84508
    Database pages     25577
    Old database pages 9461
    Modified db pages  0
    Pending reads      0
    Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
    Pages made young 0, not young 0
    0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
    Pages read 25524, created 53, written 597
    0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
    Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
    Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
    LRU len: 25577, unzip_LRU len: 0
    I/O sum[0]:cur[267], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
    ---BUFFER POOL 4
    Buffer pool size   114674
    Free buffers       86213
    Database pages     23876
    Old database pages 8833
    Modified db pages  0
    Pending reads      0
    Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
    Pages made young 0, not young 0
    0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
    Pages read 23873, created 3, written 515
    0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
    Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
    Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
    LRU len: 23876, unzip_LRU len: 0
    I/O sum[0]:cur[267], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
    ---BUFFER POOL 5
    Buffer pool size   114674
    Free buffers       85724
    Database pages     24365
    Old database pages 9014
    Modified db pages  0
    Pending reads      0
    Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
    Pages made young 2, not young 0
    0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
    Pages read 24316, created 49, written 701
    0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
    Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
    Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
    LRU len: 24365, unzip_LRU len: 0
    I/O sum[0]:cur[267], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
    ---BUFFER POOL 6
    Buffer pool size   114674
    Free buffers       84226
    Database pages     25855
    Old database pages 9564
    Modified db pages  0
    Pending reads      0
    Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
    Pages made young 2, not young 0
    0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
    Pages read 25853, created 2, written 521
    0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
    Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
    Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
    LRU len: 25855, unzip_LRU len: 0
    I/O sum[0]:cur[267], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
    ---BUFFER POOL 7
    Buffer pool size   114674
    Free buffers       85738
    Database pages     24343
    Old database pages 9005
    Modified db pages  0
    Pending reads      0
    Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
    Pages made young 0, not young 0
    0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
    Pages read 24343, created 0, written 499
    0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
    Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
    Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
    LRU len: 24343, unzip_LRU len: 0
    I/O sum[0]:cur[267], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
    --------------
    ROW OPERATIONS
    --------------
    0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
    4 read views open inside InnoDB
    Process ID=17561, Main thread ID=139839359936256, state: sleeping
    Number of rows inserted 18536, updated 78, deleted 130, read 185651761
    46.90 inserts/s, 0.50 updates/s, 1.05 deletes/s, 1648120.55 reads/s
    ----------------------------
    END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
    =========================
```

VM Stat details

```
    procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
     r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
    18  0  67756 175424 144072 10294832    0    1   307    90   67  184 35  1 61  3  0
    22  0  67756 175152 144072 10294860    0    0     0   240 9482 10164 94  1  5  0  0
     4  0  67756 174408 144072 10294876    0    0     0    76 9538 11227 93  1  6  0  0
    20  0  67756 173292 144080 10294892    0    0    16   488 9785 11370 94  1  6  0  0
    15  0  67756 172548 144084 10294928    0    0    16   228 9550 10906 95  1  4  0  0
    16  0  67756 171060 144084 10294940    0    0     0     0 9059 10031 93  1  6  0  0
    10  0  67756 176268 144096 10294928    0    0     0   276 9489 10208 92  1  7  0  0
    15  0  67756 175772 144096 10294972    0    0     0   284 8886 8658 94  1  6  0  0
    15  1  67756 174904 144100 10294976    0    0     0  6412 9815 11459 92  1  6  0  0
    23  0  67756 174160 144108 10295228    0    0     0   272 9338 9683 95  1  4  0  0
```

[image]

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Slow Query Log is one of the BEST friends you will ever find.  Get it enabled with log_output=FILE, slow_query_log=1, long_query_time=5   seconds.  And correcting just ONE frequently used query a WEEK will be beneficial.